# How to skip dummy model from django test

Tags: django

I have created one django admin page which is associated with a dummy model which doesn't exists.

Here is the code. The statistic model doesn't exists in database.

```
class StatisticModel(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Statistic'


class StatisticModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = StatisticModel

    def get_urls(self):
        view_name = 'changelist'
        return [
            path('settings/', my_custom_view, name=view_name),
        ]


admin.site.register(StatisticModel, StatisticModelAdmin)
```

In my git workflow I have below command,

```
python backend/django/manage.py test ./backend/django
```

Which is failing with error,

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "monitor_statisticmodel" does not exist
```

Please advise how can I avoid or skip this error?

Comment: Why do you have the model?

Comment: I am creating an admin page which is not associated with existing model. Because all models are already registered with other admin pages.

Comment: So I have found this work around. I need to create an admin page which shows some statistic.

Comment: But why do you have a model? You can't use the admin page of a model that doesn't exist!?

Comment: So I have below line of code to register the page, and it needs model.
admin.site.register(StatisticModel, StatisticModelAdmin)

Comment: Yeah but the admin is for editing the data on the database that the model controls, what do you need the model for if it doesn't represent a database table?

Comment: You are right that admin is for editing the data but I need to see some statistic of existing data at one place. So that I am trying to add one page for that reason created this dummy model. Is there any other better way to do it?

Comment: Yes, there are custom admin views, sending an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls

This allows you to create admin pages with custom views without requiring models.

Comment: Got it, this is what i was looking for. Thank you so much for your advise. Have a wonderful day.

Comment: I have followed the exact steps, as of now it is not producing any error however I do not see any link in admin site which points to my page.

Comment: That only adds the view and the url, they don't show up in the admin page by default, you can add them to the navbar by overriding one of the templates in basedir/templates/admin/base.html or something

Comment: Sorry for asking too many questions. The above code will go in admin.py or views.py?

Comment: In admin module, in the admin class

Comment: The url for new admin page is still not visible. I have posted new question here,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68051519/django-how-to-add-admin-page-without-using-model

Answer (score 0):

Before my answer: why bother have this model if it's not going to be used? If it's only there for testing, write "abstract = True" in the Meta class. If you don't want to do that then...

---

Maybe setting `abstract=True` would work? I'm not sure it will since Django's ModelAdmin might raise an error. What I'd advise is Django doesn't is setting "IS_TESTING" in your settings file. Imo, you should have multiple settings file. Then your model can look like:

```py
class StatisticModel(models.Model)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Statistic"
        abstract = getattr(settings, "IS_TESTING", False)
```

Another example is via a monkey patch and assuming that model is in `admin.py`. So during your test case, you can run this before your tests begin:

```
from project import admin

admin.StatisticModel.Meta.abstract = True
```

Comment: I tried both approaches but it did not work. Still producing the same error.

Comment: psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "monitor_statisticmodel" does not exist
45
LINE 1: ...OLD FOR SELECT "monitor_statisticmodel"."id" FROM "monitor_s...