# Django how to add admin page without using model

Tags: django

I needed to create a admin page which is not associated with any model. I have followed the below documentation.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls

So my admin.py looks like this,

```
from django.urls import path
from django.http import HttpResponse

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()

        my_urls = [
            path('statistic/', self.my_custom_view),
        ]
        return my_urls + urls

    def my_custom_view(request):
        .
        .
        .
        return HttpResponse(html)
```

When I login to admin site, I am not able to see the link for this view.

Then I added below line to the above code,

```
admin.site.register(MyModelAdmin)
```

It is not working.

Please advise what I am doing wrong.

Comment: As your documentation states,  AdminSite provides a get_urls() method that can be overridden to define additional views for the site.

Comment: That is already tried in above code but it is not working as expected.

Comment: ModelAdmin is not AdminSite

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
    my_urls = [
            path('statistic/', self.my_custom_view),
        ]
        return my_urls + urls
```

try

```
    my_urls = [
            path('statistic/', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.my_custom_view)),
        ]
        return my_urls + urls
```

Comment: Yes, I have already tried that, it did not help. I cannot see my link in admin site.

Comment: Yes Sorry I re read your post. I honestly dont know if there is a way to add custom links to the side bar, there are for models. Without modifying the template of course. I wanted to do the same and just overrode the template itself. I havent gone through the source code too much but Im assuming somewhere it looks for a model and then creates a link. No model, no link.